# How to get URI on Android DOCUMENT folder

Tags: kotlin, file, uri

I am building an app that should read Excel-files. Made with the Excel-app.
The plan is to store the files in the DOCUMENTS folder so it can be read from my app.
I have problems getting access to the DOCUMENTS folder.

I get: **Unknown URI: content://media/external_primary/file** when I

```
            imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, contentValues) 
            == **this cuses the error** ===
```

Can anyone give me a helping hand here?

Regards

The code I use to set the URI is this:

```
            val collection =
                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            val dirDest = File(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,
                context.getString(R.string.app_name)
            )
            val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val fileName = "test.xlsx"
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                put(
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                    "$dirDest${File.separator}"
                )
                put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
            }
```